# Deleting workspace Cargo.toml triggers version error

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm reading a rust [project](https://github.com/aurora-is-near/rainbow-bridge/tree/master/eth2near). Deleting the workspace `cargo.toml` and run test in `eth_rpc_client` gives out following error. I'm speculating if there's something around patch.crate-io, but `cargo.toml` of `eth_rpc_client` use same version as workspace does.

```
➜  eth_rpc_client git:(master) ✗ cargo test
    Updating crates.io index
    Updating git repository `https://github.com/aurora-is-near/lighthouse.git`
error: failed to select a version for the requirement `eth2_hashing = "^0.3.0"`
candidate versions found which didn't match: 0.2.0, 0.1.0
location searched: crates.io index
required by package `merkle_proof v0.2.0 (https://github.com/aurora-is-near/lighthouse.git?tag=v3.5.1-wasm#ce4e2b44)`
    ... which satisfies git dependency `merkle_proof` of package `eth_rpc_client v0.1.0 (/Users/paulyu/paul_playground/rainbow-bridge/eth2near/eth_rpc_client)`
```

```
.
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml // workspace cargo.toml
├── contract_wrapper
├── eth2-contract-init
├── eth2near-block-relay
├── eth2near-block-relay-rs
├── eth_rpc_client
├── ethashproof
├── finality-update-verify
├── logger
├── rust-toolchain
└── target
```

workspace `Cargo.toml`

```
[workspace]

members = [
    "contract_wrapper",
    "eth2-contract-init",
    "eth2near-block-relay-rs",
    "eth_rpc_client",
    "finality-update-verify",
    "logger",
]

[patch]
[patch.crates-io]
eth2_ssz = { git = "https://github.com/aurora-is-near/lighthouse.git", tag = "v3.5.1-wasm"  }
eth2_ssz_types = { git = "https://github.com/aurora-is-near/lighthouse.git", tag = "v3.5.1-wasm"  }
eth2_hashing = { git = "https://github.com/aurora-is-near/lighthouse.git", tag = "v3.5.1-wasm"  }
tree_hash = { git = "https://github.com/aurora-is-near/lighthouse.git", tag = "v3.5.1-wasm"}
tree_hash_derive = { git = "https://github.com/aurora-is-near/lighthouse.git", tag = "v3.5.1-wasm"}
eth2_serde_utils = { git = "https://github.com/aurora-is-near/lighthouse.git", tag = "v3.5.1-wasm" }
eth2_ssz_derive = { git = "https://github.com/aurora-is-near/lighthouse.git", tag = "v3.5.1-wasm" }
```

package `Cargo.toml`

```
[package]
name = "eth_rpc_client"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
types =  { git = "https://github.com/aurora-is-near/lighthouse.git", tag = "v3.5.1-wasm" }
tree_hash = { git = "https://github.com/aurora-is-near/lighthouse.git", tag = "v3.5.1-wasm" }
merkle_proof = { git = "https://github.com/aurora-is-near/lighthouse.git", tag = "v3.5.1-wasm" }
eth2_hashing = { git = "https://github.com/aurora-is-near/lighthouse.git", tag = "v3.5.1-wasm" }
eth2_ssz = { git = "https://github.com/aurora-is-near/lighthouse.git", tag = "v3.5.1-wasm" }
log = { version = "0.4", features = ["std", "serde"] }
serde_json = "1.0.74"
serde = { version = "1.0", features = ["derive"] }
ethereum-types = { version = "0.14.1", features = ["rlp", "serialize"],  default-features = false }
reqwest = { version = "0.11", features = ["blocking"] }
eth-types = { path = "../../contracts/near/eth-types/" }
contract_wrapper = { path = "../contract_wrapper" }
clap = { version = "3.1.6", features = ["derive"] }
tokio = { version = "1.1", features = ["macros", "rt", "time"] }
env_logger = "0.9.0"
borsh = "0.9.3"
futures = { version = "0.3.21", default-features = false }
async-std = "1.12.0"
hex = "*"
toml = "0.5.9"
finality-update-verify = { path = "../finality-update-verify" }
atomic_refcell = "0.1.8"
bitvec = "*"

prometheus = { version = "0.9", features = ["process"] }
lazy_static = "1.4"
warp = "0.2"
thread = "*"
dotenv = "0.15.0"
```

ref: https://github.com/aurora-is-near/rainbow-bridge/tree/master/eth2near

Comment: "Deleting Cargo.toml" isn't a thing that's supposed to work. What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: I was trying to take part of the functionality from this project and implement my own stuff, and I didn’t add workspace cargo. Then it spins off this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the `[patch]` section is very important.

The `eth2_hashing` dependency in your `eth_rpc_client` crate points to the correct GitHub repository, but that's not what is causing the error. Notice the "required by package merkle_proof" in the error message. If we look at the [`Cargo.toml` of the merkle_proof package](https://github.com/aurora-is-near/lighthouse/blob/v3.5.1-wasm/consensus/merkle_proof/Cargo.toml), it contains:

```toml
[dependencies]
eth2_hashing = "0.3.0"
```

This will try to look for version 0.3.0 of it on crates.io, which [doesn't exist](https://crates.io/crates/eth2_hashing/versions). Having the `[patch]` section will essentially redirect where that package is found.

To resolve this, you can either change *all* the packages in your GitHub repository to point to each other explicitly, or include a `[patch.crates-io]` in your `eth_rpc_client` package. If you have multiple packages needing it, consider keeping them in a workspace so you can have your patches all in one place.

Comment: May I clarify “ change all the packages in your GitHub repository to point to each other explicitly” do you mean point to each other correctly? Like having  Merkle_tree point to 0.2.0 (available version on crate io)?

Comment: I was under the impression you had forked the whole lighthouse repository and thus should make all your forked packages point to other forked packages. But if the ones hosted on crates.io are sufficient then that is easiest.